# SQL / SQLite, need query to check all of the strings in a column

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, row

I have a table with the following columns

`[itemdate][itemID][itemspecialid]`

itemID contains a string with multiple ideas, (ie. `[54] [60] [96] [30]`) as it is a set of IDs, only some entries have an `itemspecialid` which is actually only associated with one [itemID] of the set.

I am actually using java, so I will be parsing each [itemID] entry using `myString.contains("[60]")` which will have retrieved an `itemID` string set from the database, and then compared within `myString` looking for a particular value.

What would the SQL query be for selecting rows with `[itemspecialid]`'s populated? Once I get the basic query I can figure out how this is done within my language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly, but if you want to get the rows where itemspecialid is not null, the query is

```
select itemdate, itemID, itemspecialid from mytable where itemspecialid is not null
```

It's a bad idea to store multiple information inside a single column. You should have a separate table to store the itemIDs of your items.

Comment: +1 : That does seem to be what's being asked, and I too grimace at the idea of a single field with multiple IDs stored as a string.

Comment: you're right - now that I'm looking at this problem again after a break. Earlier I was hung up on some SQL basics like how to address a second table with a common key so I opted for using an element that I already knew I could search. (string)